How to tile a sculpted plane seamlessly?
I created a test plane that has a size of 1m that I sculpted. In the Sculpting tool settings, I set them like so (I've experimented with Feather off as well):

When I add the 2 below Array modifiers, I noticed the seams are quite noticable.

The orthographic, topdown view looks okay-ish...I still see seams. But then this perspective view looks really bad. How can I ensure there are no seams?



Watching your video, I see that typing the coordinates is not the solution (because X and Y are locked and they're not the problem). Them main problem is that 0.33m is not one third. 1/3 = 0.333333333333333333333... to infinity (you can type 1/3 in the box for the tiling) @NataliaDaLomba

In the Brush Settings > Advanced, try enabling the Original Normal option. (When Locked keep using normal of surface where stroke was initiated).
In the example below I have simplified the Array to a Count of 2 along X :

and in the Brush setting I have set the tile Offset to 0.5 for X and Y (exactly 4 pattern repeats across the surface being sculpted):

Gaps are visible along the array border.
With the Brush Settings > Advanced > Original Normal option checked, there is no visible gap at the array border.

This will not work when we try for a repeat pattern count of 9 when, as in your video example the X and Y Tile Offset are set to 0.33m. This will not give an exact repeat across the surface. 1 divided by 3 is only approximately 0.33 (repeating).

Setting the Tile Offset to more accurate 0.333333m and enabling the Original Normal option does apparently result in no visible gaps (seams) at the array border.

NOTE:
Something I have just noticed is that if the Merge option is enabled in Array modifiers this prevents the surface from splitting at the Array borders during sculpting although there is still a visible seam and that this slight seam is still visible after applying the Array modifiers.
From my very limited experience I would suggest you leave the Merge option unchecked completely then after applying the modifiers, in Edit mode with all selected use the M key to open the Merge menu and choose the By distance option to merge all the vertices that were along the array borders.

This worked!!!! Thank you so much for this thorough answer. My hero xD Also thank you
@DanielMöller for helping :)
